# Can I select All Whatsapp Contacts Programmatically and then send message to them on single click

Tags: android

I want to send a message using whatsapp only to a particular contact without the user having to select it from his contact list. I am using the below code to fire an intent

```
       try {  
        String num= "+918888888888"; // contains spaces.
        num= num.replace("+", "").replace(" ", "");

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        sendIntent.putExtra("jid", num+ "@s.whatsapp.net");
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Test");
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    app.showSnackBar(parentView, "Whatsapp have not been installed.");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

no that is not possible u will have to get user permission for that through your manifest so that u will have to show the user a list of contacts